# How to pass JSON response to array with model in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, model

my JSON response look like this:

```
"result": {
    "data": {
        "open": [
            {
                "user_id": "10",
                "request_title": "Title-2",
                "category": "4"
            }
            {
                "user_id": "10",
                "request_title": "Title-2",
                "category": "4"
            }.....
            ]
```

for that i have created MODEL like this:

for every corresponding value in model i will create like this:

```
public class Result {
public var status : Status?
public var data : PostedData?

public class func modelsFromDictionaryArray(array:NSArray) -> [Result]
{
    var models:[Result] = []
    for item in array
    {
        models.append(Result(dictionary: item as! NSDictionary)!)
    }
    return models
}


required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

    if (dictionary["status"] != nil) { status = Status(dictionary: dictionary["status"] as! NSDictionary) }
    if (dictionary["data"] != nil) { data = PostedData(dictionary: dictionary["data"] as! NSDictionary) }
}


public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> NSDictionary {

    let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    dictionary.setValue(self.status?.dictionaryRepresentation(), forKey: "status")
    dictionary.setValue(self.data?.dictionaryRepresentation(), forKey: "data")

    return dictionary
}

}
```

this is PostedData:

```
public class PostedData {
public var open : [Open]?
public var all : [All]?

required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

    if (dictionary["open"] != nil) { open = Open.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: dictionary["open"] as! NSArray) }

    if (dictionary["all"] != nil) { all = All.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: dictionary["all"] as! NSArray) }
}
}


public class Open {
public var user_id : String?
public var request_title : String?
}
```

and i am able to get JSON response.. but which is unable to add MOdel

here i am getting JSON response:

```
          var postModel: PostedServiceBase?

     if let code = ((resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
     // here i am trying to add JSON resp to model
     self?.postModel = PostedServiceBase(dictionary: resp.responseDict as? NSDictionary ?? NSDictionary())                    
     let totalData = code["data"] as? [String : Any]
      if let open = totalData?["open"] as? [[String : Any]]{
      for (value) in open {
                    
            }
        }
```

**here i need to add `open` array value to `servicesArray`**.. but how i am unable to do that

```
  self?.servicesArray.append(ServicesModel(header: self?.allValues?.request_title, title: self?.allValues?.request_title, userId: self?.allValues?.userid))
```

please. do help to add JSON values to array with model... i cant use codable protocal in this case

Comment: It's quite rude to people that have tried to help you to delete your [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016627/how-to-create-model-for-json-response-in-swift) question only to re-post it again a few hours later.

Comment: Where you call the API create a variable with the type of that model and assign the response to that variable, Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

U can use `JSONDecoder` to transform json into objects:

```
import Foundation

let json = """
    {
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "open": [
          {
            "user_id": "10",
            "request_title": "Title-2",
            "category": "4"
          },
          {
            "user_id": "10",
            "request_title": "Title-2",
            "category": "4"
          }
        ]
       }
      }
    }
"""

print(json)

struct TestJSON: Codable {
  var result: Result
}

struct Result: Codable {
  var data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
  var dataOpen: [Open]

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case dataOpen = "open"
  }
}

struct Open: Codable {
  var userid: String
  var requestTitle: String
  var category: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userid = "user_id"
    case requestTitle = "request_title"
    case category
  }
}

extension Open: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  var debugDescription: String {
    "userid: " + userid + " " +
      "requestTitle " + requestTitle + " " +
        "category " + category
  }
}

extension DataClass: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  var debugDescription: String {
    dataOpen
      .map{ "Obj value: " + $0.debugDescription }
      .joined(separator: "\n")
  }
}

extension Result: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  var debugDescription: String {
    data.debugDescription
  }
}

extension TestJSON: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  var debugDescription: String {
    result.debugDescription
  }
}

let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)
if let jsonData = jsonData {
  let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
  do {
    let testJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(TestJSON.self, from: jsonData)
    print(testJSON)
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
} else {
  print("can't convert json string into data")
}
```

Output in console:

> Obj value: userid: 10 requestTitle Title-2 category 4
>
> Obj value: userid: 10 requestTitle Title-2 category 4

Comment: this is existing project.. they already created all models.. so i cant use codable.. pls do help with my code

Comment: @iosswift in u'r code  `for (value) in open { }}` value is a dictionary that holds all 3 values, so just use subscript to access each value than and cast it to expected type, like `value["title"] as? String` or so, than create u'r `ServicesModel` using received values.

Comment: to which variable in model should i add `value["title"] as? String`, this thing i am unable to do

Comment: u have `ServicesModel` init, that accept 3 values, so create local variables (all that is needed for init) and than pass them in to constructor of `ServicesModel` like `let title = value["title"] as? String` and other values and then `ServicesModel(header: title,...)`

Comment: yes with local variable i am able to do.. but i need it using MODEL.. i need to add JSON response to model.. and call them in each place(like open.. i have close and all ) options so i need to show its values as well